# PDO Cannot Connect to Remote MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've recently setup a load balancer, it has 3 public servers serving users.
Here's where I have my problem... the site uses PDO to connect to database, the MySQL server is on one single remote server for all them to connect to and it doesn't seem to work.
Here's the error I get:
"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /var/www/pingrglobe.com/backend/database.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/pingrglobe.com/backend/database.php(8): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=162....', 'root', 'nope') #1 /var/www/pingrglobe.com/structure/header.php(4): require('/var/www/pingrg...') #2 /var/www/pingrglobe.com/index.php(2): require('/var/www/pingrg...') #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/pingrglobe.com/backend/database.php on line 8"

Here's my code:

```
$host = "162.243.135.167";
$user = "root";
$pass = "nope;)";
$dbname = "pingrglobe";
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";port=3306;dbname=".$dbname, $user, $pass);
```

Comment: Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

Comment: I'll type what I think would work:

Comment: sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
Worked. I love you. :) Put that as an answer, I will tick it!

Comment: @RPM Wordpress? MySQL extension? This is a PDO question.